# NextAuth with Google Provider needs to open a pop-up

Tags: next.js, google-oauth, next-auth

Here's my app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.js and I want when users do sign in it doesn't redirect to a new page rather than opens up a small pop up with the same Google window, so the user stays on the website.

```
import NextAuth from 'next-auth'
import GoogleProvider from 'next-auth/providers/google'
import sendEmailToUser from '@/utils/email'

export const authOptions = {
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async signIn({ user, account, profile, email, credentials }) {
      if (user && user.email) {
        try {
          await sendEmailToUser(user.email);
          return true; 
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error saving user:
          return false; 
        }
      }
      return true;
    },
  },
}

export const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);
export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

{redirect:false} doesn't work though. And I don't need a new page, I just need same Google sign in page just shown in a pop up window. what ways can it be done?

I've implemented a custom React hook using NextAuth.js to handle Google authentication in a popup window. The hook works as intended in full-screen mode by opening a new tab, refreshing, and closing itself upon successful authentication. However, in non-full-screen mode, where it opens as a popup, it doesn't refresh or close after a successful sign-in. Interestingly, resizing the popup window seems to trigger a refresh.

Here's the relevant part of my custom hook:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useSession } from 'next-auth/react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

const usePopupWindow = (url = '', title = 'Popup', width = 500, height = 550) => {
  const { data: session, status } = useSession();
  const [popup, setPopup] = useState(null);
  const router = useRouter();

  const openPopup = () => {
    // Logic to open the popup
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      if (status === 'authenticated') {
        clearInterval(interval);
        if (popup && !popup.closed) {
          popup.close();
        }
        router.refresh();
      } else if (popup && popup.closed) {
        clearInterval(interval);
      }
    }, 1000);

    return () => {
      // Cleanup logic
    };
  }, [status, popup, router]);

  return { openPopup, popup };
};

export default usePopupWindow;
```

And here's how I use this hook in my component:

```
import usePopupWindow from "@/hooks/usePopupWindow";

const { openPopup, popup } = usePopupWindow(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_WEBSITE_URL}/api/auth/signin/google`, 'Google');

const handleLogin = async () => {
  openPopup();
};
```

I would like the popup to redirect immediately to the Google sign-in page instead of showing an intermediate button. Also, after successful authentication, the popup and the main website should refresh, similar to how it behaves in full-screen mode.

Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve these issues would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be split in to two parts:

1. Open the new window
2. Sign-in on the new window

For the first part, you can use a function similar to this:

```js
function popupCenter(url, title) {
  const dualScreenLeft = window.screenLeft ?? window.screenX;
  const dualScreenTop = window.screenTop ?? window.screenY;

  const width =
    window.innerWidth ?? document.documentElement.clientWidth ?? screen.width;

  const height =
    window.innerHeight ??
    document.documentElement.clientHeight ??
    screen.height;

  const systemZoom = width / window.screen.availWidth;

  const left = (width - 500) / 2 / systemZoom + dualScreenLeft;
  const top = (height - 550) / 2 / systemZoom + dualScreenTop;

  const newWindow = window.open(
    url,
    title,
    `width=${500 / systemZoom},height=${550 / systemZoom
    },top=${top},left=${left}`
  );

  newWindow?.focus();
};
```

This simply opens a new window in the center of the user's screen and then sets the focus to it. Now, it's time to build the window that is opened.

```js
// /app/google-login/page.js

'use client'

export default function SignInPopUpPage() {
    const { data: session, status } = useSession()

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!(status === "loading") && !session) {
            signIn("google");
        }
        if (session) {
            window.close();
        }
    }, [session, status]);

    return (
        <div
            style={{
                width: "100vw",
                height: "100vh",
                position: "absolute",
                left: 0,
                top: 0,
                background: "white",
            }}
        />
    );
};
```

To finish, have your login button call the function `popupCenter`, with the `SignInPopUpPage` route as the URL.

This has been adapted to use the app router from [this repo](https://github.com/arye321/nextauth-google-popup-login).

Comment: Thank you so much. I actually created a hook from it, but I'm now facing another issue. When I'm in not full scree mode it opens a popup, everything works great, (though would love immediately to redirect to Google Sign in page but it shows another button). So when user successfully signs in it doesn't refresh the popup and the website behind, but in full screen when it opens a tab it refreshes, closes itself so everything works perfect. Also strange when I tried to resize the popup it refreshed itself. So here's my code

Comment: This doesn't close the popup. All it does is to keep the user on a new window, but the previous old one remains untouched. Or am I missing something?